# Retrofit Form Encoded and Multipart in single request

Tags: android, retrofit

```
public interface PostMessage {
@Multipart
@POST("https://www.example.com/message")
void sendMessage(@QueryMap Map<String, String> queryMap,
        @Part("image") TypedFile imagefile, Callback<Response> response);
}
```

I tried encryption of queryMap with @Feild and @Body. But it's giving **IllegalArgumentException** with message **"Only one encoding annotation is allowed"**.

**My Question is :**
In a same request can data encryption done with multipart ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just for sharing: Another way to do this is-

```js
public interface PostMessage {
@Multipart
@POST("https://www.example.com/message")
void sendMessage(@PartMap Map<String, String> partMap,
        @Part("image") TypedFile imagefile, Callback<Response> response);
}
```

UPDATE: With Retrofit2

```
public interface PostMessage {
@Multipart
@POST("https://www.example.com/message")
Call<Response> sendMessage(@PartMap Map<String, String> partMap,
        @Part("image") TypedFile imagefile);
}
```

Comment: Hey any clue on this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30411672/how-to-add-nodejs-s3-heroku-direct-upload-to-android